# Logical List of HashMap error?

Tags: java, list, for-loop, hashmap

Not sure how to phrase this question. I have a dummy code here for a bootcamp/training exercise. I have a list of hash maps that I want to set in this loop as it goes through the ingredients. The code runs without error, however all of the ingredients in the list of hash maps are always set to the last one. It appears as if each one is over writing the previous one. Here is my code:

```
List<Map<String,String>> returner= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        Map<String,String> resultant = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for ( Ingredient current : webIngredients ) {//loop through each ingredient in list of ingredients
            resultant.put("Ingredient", current.getIngredientName());
            resultant.put("Quantity", current.getQuantity());
            resultant.put("Unit", current.getMeasureType());
            recipe.getFields().add(resultant);//using a recipe. Not used in test
            returner.add(resultant);//add first hashmap to the list
        }//end for: loop through records (file lines)
```

So basically I want to read in the ingredients from the ingredient object which has three properties, ingredientname, quantity, and unit (the measurement). So if I give it lettuce,2,slice  and tomato,1,slice then I should get a list with maps Ingredient:lettuce Quantity:2 Unit:slice, Ingredient:tomato quanity:1 unit:slice

Comment: I moved the map declaration inside the for loop and the issue still persists. What else could be causing this?

Comment: My mistake, you are right the issue was with memory error on the web logic server I was deploying the web service too. Sorry and thanks for taking the time to try and help me. I guess I deserved the -2s...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized `Map<String,String> resultant = new HashMap<String,String>();` outside the for loop;

When the first time for loop run the maps get populated with certain values.

When the loop runs the second time the map object values get overridden because it's the same map object on the heap. That's why it is taking the last value;

just put the `Map<String,String> resultant = new HashMap<String,String>();` inside the for loop so every time a new map object is created.

Comment: the old one won't be garbage collected (and nor would you want it to be) - it's referenced in the lists

Comment: Issue listed would be solved by this thanks, my issue was with service deployment. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Because you're only creating a single map, you *are* overwriting the details each time. You need to create a new map each time inside the loop:

```
List<Map<String,String>> returner= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    for ( Ingredient current : webIngredients ) {//loop through each ingredient in list of ingredients
        // create a map for this ingredient
        Map<String,String> resultant = new HashMap<String,String>();

        resultant.put("Ingredient", current.getIngredientName());
        resultant.put("Quantity", current.getQuantity());
        resultant.put("Unit", current.getMeasureType());
        recipe.getFields().add(resultant);//using a recipe. Not used in test
        returner.add(resultant);//add this hashmap to the list
    }//end for: loop through records (file lines)
```

Comment: Sorry the issue was with a web service deployment on my end.